# What is the best way to avoid XPath Injection attack in Java?

Tags: java, xml, security, xpath

I am using XPath to retrieve values from XML.  My code scanner break the build because of the following reason:

> invokes an XPath query built using unvalidated input. This call could
>   allow an attacker to modify the statement's meaning or to

This is my code:

```
private String myMethod(String XPath, OMElement input) {
  String elementText = null;
  AXIOMXPath xpathToElement = null;
  try {
    xpathToElement = new AXIOMXPath(XPath);
    xpathToElement.addNamespace(xxx,yyy);
    elementText = ((OMElement) xpathToElementnode.selectSingleNode(input)).getText();

  } catch (JaxenException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    fail(e.getMessage());
  ...
```

Here is the code where I call above method:

```
key = myMethod(myAttribute.getAttributeValue(), input);
```

`input` is `OMelement` which contains XML. Attribute is getting from XML attribute.

How can I avoid XPathInjection?  Could please share a code snippet?

Comment: Show the code that's in violation to receive specific help.

Comment: added my code in last edit

Comment: You don't show the calls to `myMethod()`.  If user input can reach the first argument to `myMethod()`, you are at risk.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking an *entire* XPath from user input or other external source?

**Recommendation: *Do not take in a full XPath expression an unsecured source.***   Use precompiled XPaths.  If you have to parameterize your XPath based on user input, isolate the user-based parts to *string-only* parameters, and then use your XPath library's parameterization mechanism.

You're using Java and Axiom, which is based on Jaxen, so use [SimpleVariableContext](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/apidocs/org/jaxen/SimpleVariableContext.html) and [setVariableContext()](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/apidocs/org/jaxen/BaseXPath.html#setVariableContext(org.jaxen.VariableContext)) for XPath parameterization.  See Charles Duffy's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30353837/290085) for more details on safely parameterizing XPaths when using Axiom.

Comment: I am getting the xpath as whole text and it doesn't contain any parameters. My xpath is like `//a/b[x=y]/d`.

Comment: Can you not embed such a fixed XPath in the code you control such that it can be precompiled?