# How to use variables in Velocity XPath expressions?

Tags: xml, xpath, velocity

If I provide constant "1" in `rollnumber[1]`

```
/root/person/rollnumber[1]
```

XPath evaluates fine.

But instead of a constant, I want to provide some variable

```
/root/person/rollnumber[$i]
```

where `$i` can be any integer.

This XPath expression does not work.

Comment: How/Where did you set the value of `$i`?

Comment: I am writing this xpath in velocity tempalte. so, i can set it #set($i = 1)

Comment: Since `$i` is a velocity template's variable, I strongly suspect this is velocity-specific question. XPath 1.0 itself doesn't have notion of `$` variable

Comment: Yes you are right. seems like xpath doesn't have notion of $ variable. i saw one eg which says $ can be used. but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The usual trick is to assemble the XPath using string formatting or concatenation within the hosting language environment.

Try this in Velocity:

```
#set($xp = "/root/person/rollnumber[${i}]")
```

Then use `$xp` in place of the string literal in your XPath call.

See also [How to pass parameter into XPath expression in Xpath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30352671/290085) for how to do this in other hosting languages.