# How to use Python variable in an XPath expression?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am trying to get all the `followers name` from this website https://www.quora.com/profile/Karan-Bansal-3/followers

Since the whole page is not loaded at once, I am using this everytime in a loop :

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Now since I can't select all the element at once, I am trying to use indexing to find the element in the loop.

```
people = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pagedlist_item'][i]/*/div[@class='ObjectCard-header']/a[@class='user']")
```

Here as you can see, I am trying to give the indexing using `[i]` which clearly doesn't work and in place of it, if I give [1] or any number it works well. So how can I select the element one by one.

Code snippet :

```
i=1
target = open(filename,'w')
driver.get('https://www.quora.com/profile/Karan-Bansal-3/followers')
while True:
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
people = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pagedlist_item'][i]/*/div[@class='ObjectCard-header']/a[@class='user']")
target.write(people.text)
target.write("\n")
i = i+1
```

Comment: Are you replacing the variable "i" by its value?

Comment: @derloopkat I have shown that `i` is 1 initially and I know XPATH is not taking the variable `[i]`, so how can it be selected then because I need all the elements and it can only be done in a loop which will increment the value and so will the index.

Answer (score 2):

Use string concatenation in the hosting language so that `i` is evaluated before constructing the XPath.  Otherwise, `[i]` is a predicate testing for the presence of an `i` element.  You didn't state what your hosting language is, but assuming string concatenation is `"string" + "string"`:

```
 "//div[@class='pagedlist_item'][" + i + "]/*/div[@class='ObjectCard-header']/a[@class='user']"
```

See also: [How to pass variable parameter into XPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352671/how-to-pass-variable-parameter-into-xpath-expression)

---

**Update**: Ok, so you're hosting XPath in Python.

You can use `+` to concatenate above if you first cast `i` to a string via `str(i)`,

```
 "//div[@class='pagedlist_item'][" + str(i) + "]/*/div[@class='ObjectCard-header']/a[@class='user']"
```

or you can use `format()` as is used in the link I provided:

```
 "//div[@class='pagedlist_item'][{}]/*/div[@class='ObjectCard-header']/a[@class='user']".format(i)
```

either way, place the above constructed XPath expressions into your call to `find_element_by_xpath()` and your problem should be solved.

***Caution***: Do not use this approach with untrusted values for `i` or you could open your code to [XPath injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XPATH_Injection).

Comment: this is quite basic, if you're using Phyton then check how to do a for in range.

Comment: Updated answer for Python for you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly cast index/i variable to string using str(index) and then 
try using below:

content = rows.xpath('//div[@class="LookupHelpDesc"][**'+index+'**]//text()').extract_first()

always use **single** quote.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to first convert the index to a string.

```
index = str(i)
people = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pagedlist_item'][" + index + "]/*/div[@class='ObjectCard-header']/a[@class='user']")
i++
```