# Using list variables in xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to grab the cover of the book on this HTML. The cover sometimes is at the first order, sometimes it is at the second order.

```
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <b>Series</b>
            Campell
        </li>
        <li>
            <b>Hardcover:</b>
            1465 pages
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I put the cover types in this list

```
cover = ['Hardcover', 'BoardBook', 'CardBook']
```

When I specifically write `'Hardcover'` in the xpath, it works.

```
response.xpath("//li/b[contains(text(),'Hardcover')]/text()").extract()
```

However, when I use the index of the list `cover[0]`, it brings other things as well.

```
response.xpath('//li/b[contains(text(),cover[0])]/text()').extract()
```

I want to iterate the list values to check one of them between tags.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to use Python variable in an XPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323317/how-to-use-python-variable-in-an-xpath-expression) and [How to pass variable parameter into XPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352671/how-to-pass-variable-parameter-into-xpath-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need string concatenation :

```
response.xpath('//li/b[contains(text(), "' + cover[0] + '")]/text()').extract()
```

or

```
xpath_string = '//li/b[contains(text(), "{}")]/text()'.format(cover[0])
response.xpath(xpath_string).extract()
```

[image: warning]
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323317/how-to-use-python-variable-in-an-xpath-expression/37323529#37323529) about xpath injection