# Xpath with variable part

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have component with identifier "data-component=order-button_guid"

I would like to generate Xpath like

```
"//*[@data-component='order-button']+applicationId"
```

to have it in form
`order-button_xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable parameter into XPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352671/how-to-pass-variable-parameter-into-xpath-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the GUID with the xpath before the single quote(') as below.

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//*[@data-component='order-button+applicationId+']"))
```