# Putting multiple varilables into single XPath for Selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Suppose I have an XPath to identify an element like this:

```
//div[@id='%s1']//div[@class='%s2']
```

The values for both s1 and s2 are to be passed at runtime. Is it possible to form an XPath (String) by passing these two variables from my code?

Comment: You can build the XPath expression in Java code before calling Selenium, right?
e.g.
`String xpathToUse = "//div[@id='" + s1 + "']//div[@class='" + s2 + "']"`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable parameter into XPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352671/how-to-pass-variable-parameter-into-xpath-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String varLocator(String locator, String holder1, String param1, String holder2, String param2) {

return locator.replace(holder1, param1).replace(holder2, param2);

}

public void sample() {

String eleLocator = "//div[@id='%s1']//div[@class='%s2']";

WebElement foo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(varLocator(eleLocator, "%s1", "foo", "%s2", "bar")));

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be the solution I was looking for. will try it out.