# How to pass Python variable to XPath expression?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am currently working on a script that prints the ID of an Web Element based on a given text. Up till now I managed to do this:

```
wait.until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'my_text')]"))
ID = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'my_text')]").get_attribute("id")
print(ID)
```

The code works fine, but I want to change it so it can be used for strings other than "my_text".

How can I pass a variable to that function? Something like this:

```
variable = 'my_text'
wait.until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), variable)]"))
ID = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), variable)]").get_attribute("id")
print(ID)
```

This way I could assign any text to the variable and use the same function every time.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083073/add-variable-in-xpath-in-python.

Spoiler: There's no clean way to do this with selenium, you have to rely on string interpolation or concatenation (which is what the current accepted answer does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
variable = "my_text"
your_needed_xpath = "//*[contains(text(), '{}')]".format(variable)
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This worked just fine... but my I ask: how does that work? I mean... I understand that it creates the string needed for xpath, but how does the '{}')]".format(variable) work?

Comment: @ChiserAlexandru, this is built-in in string in Python: Here are some examples and documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples

Answer (score 1):

You can format your xpath pattern first before feeding it to the method.

```
pattern = "//*[contains(text(), %s)]" % variable
ID = browser.find_element_by_xpath(pattern).get_attribute("id")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following - just enclose the *variable* in {}, and add an "f" before the string:

```
variable = 'my_text'
wait.until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[contains(text(), {variable})]'))
ID = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[contains(text(),{variable})]').get_attribute("id")
print(ID)
```

This is called [string interpolation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well.Hope it will work.

```
 variable = 'my_text'
 wait.until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + variable + "')]"))
 ID = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + variable + "')]").get_attribute("id")
 print(ID)
```