# How to get the text value from an element based on its sibling attribute value?

Tags: xml, xpath

Example xml:

```
<root>
    <ns1:agent ns2:about="a3">
        <ns2:name xml:lang="en">Helen</ns2:name>
        <ns2:age>26</ns2:age>
    </ns1:agent>
    <ns1:agent ns2:about="a1">
        <ns2:name xml:lang="en">John</ns2:name>
        <ns2:age>26</ns2:age>
    </ns1:agent>
    <ns1:agent ns2:about="a2">
        <ns2:name xml:lang="en">Mike</ns2:name>
        <ns2:age>30</ns2:age>
    </ns1:agent>
    ...
    <!-- More ns1:agent nodes -->
    ...
    <ns3:person ns2:id="a1"/>
    <ns3:person ns2:id="a2"/>
    <ns3:person ns2:id="a3"/>
    ...
    <!-- More ns3:person nodes -->
    ...
</root>
```

So how to get the text value of the agent/name element based on its about attribute starting from person element, using XPath?

Edit:
XPath expression will be used in a loop, for each ns3:person node, so I don't know the specific id attribute value beforehand.

Comment: Your question isn't clear: what exactly do you mean by "based on its about attribute starting from person element"?

Comment: @JackFleeting I meant I need an XPath expression that starts from person element and gets 'John'.

Comment: In the original xml I have multiple "person" nodes and multiple corresponding "agent" nodes containing some data about the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for an xpath expression like this:

```
    //ns1:agent[@ns2:about=//ns3:person/@ns2:id]/ns2:name
```

To test it, I would change your `ns3:persons` nodes in your sample xml from

```
<ns3:person ns2:id="a1"/>
<ns3:person ns2:id="a2"/>
<ns3:person ns2:id="a3"/>
```

to

```
<ns3:person ns2:id="a7"/>
<ns3:person ns2:id="a2"/>
<ns3:person ns2:id="a9"/>
```

so that only one random `ns1:agent` corresponds to one random `ns3:person`. If you do that, that xpath expression would select `Mike` as the target name.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've properly declared namespace prefixes `ns1`, `ns2`, and `ns3`, this XPath,

```
//ns3:person[@ns2:id = "a1"]/preceding-sibling::ns1:agent[1]/ns2:name
```

will select the name of the agent immediately preceding the identified person.

If you need help declaring the XML namespace prefixes, see [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)

---

**Update based on OP's comment:**

> In my original xml document, the agent node is not immediately preceding the person node. I will be running the expression in a loop, for each person node. Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the example and the question so it is more clear what I need.

And in the edited question:

> Edit: XPath expression will be used in a loop, for each ns3:person node, so I don't know the specific id attribute value beforehand.

So in your loop simply bind a variable, say `$id`, to the current `ns3:person/@n2:id` and then test it in the XPath:

```
//ns1:agent[@ns2:about = $id]/ns2:name
```

See also [How to pass variable parameter into XPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30352671/290085)

Comment: In my original xml document, the agent node is not immediately preceding the person node. I will be running the expression in a loop, for each person node. Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the example and the question so it is more clear what I need. Thanks sir!